# ECharts splitLine not showing on interval function

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

What I'm trying to do is set a splitLine under the label when the label it's not an empty string:

When there's more than one value different from empty string it has the desired behavior:
[both splitLines are under the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2yu6.png)

But when there's only one value not empty, the splitLine is not showing, it appears to be aligning to the left side of the chart
[only one not empty value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkWj5.png)

This is my code:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    position: 'top',
    data: ['', '', '', 'aaa', 'bbb'],
    splitLine: {
      show: true,
      interval: function(index, value) {
        return value != '';
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 147, 260],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
}
```

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&theme=dark&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6IYHgiQYdMKF79YAE2aMiAbVq9YKnmtW1GOrQCMDtALp9SsPCAA2IgDIRoNYmfR4AFsADuRMBwCuVU2d7Fg4AN0ZLIgAzX2h6UWgACnsZKgwNcMt_AEonZ3QOKjBfDjhM_1gAQkQVAG5pdABfaWamwPIcfCJUMwpqOnKqWhJGwLwqDggqQlhFaR7nOTAFWYBGAFYABg0AJgBmbdgdnYAWDVWTgHZdgDZNkwaySkdaawdhs1bYIxRG2qA

Im expecting to have a splitLine under the label always

**UPDATE: This is a bug**
[see here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19247)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. You could do something like this to force that there is always 2 splitlines if it fits your use case:

```js
const AxisData = ['', 'b', '', '', ''];

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    position: 'top',
    data: AxisData,
    splitLine: {
      show: true,
      interval: function(index, value) {                                //   relevant
        return AxisData[index] !== '' || AxisData[index - 1] !== '';    //     part
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: It does not solve my problem, setting the sliptLine if the index is 0 solves it, but it does not work if you zoom the data with dataZoom, which is also my case, because the index does not start at 0 always